# Headphone port broken on iPad Air

Tags: ipad, headphones

When I try to put the jack in, it jumps back up and only sits when I push it really hard. I've tried with my other headphone but it's the same. On top of that the buttons (on the headphone) doesn't work. How can I fix my iPad headphone port?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Physical things can break and there are shops and people that fix them. Is there an edit you can make to explain what question you have that relates to your situation?

Comment: Looks like something is stuck in there, preventing you to fully seat the plug. Maybe a pair of very thin tweezers could help?

Comment: I think Jamie is right, something is stuck. I tried watching a video without my headphones but no sound came out. When i pressed the volume up button, the screen which shows how loud the sound is said "Headphones". I'll just try taking it to an Apple Store, thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

iFixit has great electronics repair guides and they sell parts, too (though, at times they can be overpriced). Here's the link for the [iPad Air Headphone Jack Replacement Guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPad+Air+Wi-Fi+Headphone+Jack+Replacement/25044) (it's for the Wi-Fi-only model).

I hope you have some experience with repair, because the first time when I opened up one of my customer's iPad to replace the digitizer, it was quite a task. Just consider taking your iPad to a pro before attempting the repair yourself.